# why my python program cannot find the modules although my setting is correct?

Tags: python, module, environment-variables

My colleagues shared some programs and modules with me. I put them in ...../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdbParser. Below show the content.

[image: All programs(green), modules(green), and sub-directories(magneta) are under pdbParser]

I set this directory in $PATH. However, when I run my program at another directory (let's say user directory), I received below error message.

```
  File "run.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pdbParser.pdbParser import pdbParser
  File "/<my system dir>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdbParser/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from __pkginfo__ import __version__, __author__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__pkginfo__'
```

Actually, my program (run.py) can call the module (pdbParser.py) in "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdbParser/" but the module (**pkginfo**.py) called by pdbParser.py cannot be found. I do not understand why it happened. I read related questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298465/python-m-cannot-find-my-modules) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217063/why-cant-python-find-my-module)) in this community, but I could not get the issue fixed. Is there anything wrong on my end? Any further help and suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `.pyc` files indicate Python 2. Can you verify you are running Python 3.7?

Comment: Yes. The programs shared from my colleagues were written by Python2. I tried to use them in Python 3. Honestly, I just started using Python two months ago. I have many things to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you fix the error syntax in the `__init__.py` file like this?

append `.`

from

```
from __pkginfo__ import __version__, __author__
```

to

```
from .__pkginfo__ import __version__, __author__
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. May I know why I should add dot "." in the front of the module name? Thanks.